# Oracle SQL - Last 3 full months of data

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the last 3 full months of data so March, April, and May in this case. This almost gives me what I want but it includes June 1st which I don't need. I need March 1st through May 31st.

Oracle SQL:

```
where d.D_DATE between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -3) and add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `>=` and `<` rather than `BETWEEN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   d
WHERE  d.D_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -3)
AND    d.D_DATE <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE d (D_DATE) AS
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -3) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -3) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | D_DATE |
> | --- |
> | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 |
> | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2022-05-31 00:00:01 |
> | 2022-05-31 23:59:59 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fa1d191accc62801d47561cc2730da22)*

Answer (score -1):

Got it. where d.D_DATE between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -3) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'),-1))

Comment: This will not get data between `00:00:01` and `23:59:59` on the last day of the month. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c2b74038dee134042563c2330b09d070)